# Slick way to transform this data structure hash of hashes?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, hash, transform, inject

I have the following Ruby data structure:

```
data_struct = {
  item1 => { attr1: :word_a, attr2: :word_b, attr3: :word_a},
  item2 => { attr1: :word_b, attr2: :word_a },
  item3 => {                 attr2: :word_b, attr3: :word_c}
}
```

I want to transform it to:

```
new_data_struct = {
  attr1 => { word_a: item1, word_b: item2 },
  attr2 => { word_b: [item1, item3], word_a: item2 },
  attr3 => { word_a: item1, word_c: item3 }
}
```

I have the impression I should be using `inject`, perhaps along with `fetch` and something slick with the `Hash.new()` default.

Comment: What are `item1`, `item2`, and `item3`?  Did you mean for them to be symbols or strings?  Also, can you please describe the transformation?

Comment: I think you'll find it easier to work with the transformed hash of hashes, if all values of the sub-hashes are arrays, not a mix of single elements and arrays.

Comment: The slickest way to deal with data structure transformation is to not start with a data structure to begin with.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as unclear other than not describing the transform in extreme detail. I stated 'I have data structure X with an example, I need data structure Y with the example transformed, how do I transform it? The details of what attr1, word_a, item1 etc. are unimportant and could be anything. Mr. Swoveland's answer was very informative and eye-opening. I'd love to know more about his thought process to arrive at that answer. Sure, Mr. Thomas's comment added nothing to the conversation. The other 2 answers were also very helpful - thank you!

Comment: It was closed because you didn't answer the follow up questions. Since you didn't provide any code of your own, the least you could have done is help scope it out a bit. @CarySwoveland was very generous by providing a thoughtful answer that is generalized and perhaps more than you needed.

Comment: And to try to add to my initial comment to make it more helpful:  While munging data structures is the easiest way in many languages to deal with data, in Ruby I would consider refactoring the data structure into value objects. Often this makes the code much easier to read (= more maintainable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
data_struct.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]={} }) { |(k,v),h|
  v.each {|k1,v1| h[k1].merge!({v1=>k}) { |key,ov,_|
    (ov.is_a? Array) ? ov << k : [ov,k] } } }
```

When

```
data_struct = {
  :item1 => { attr1: :word_a, attr2: :word_b, attr3: :word_a },
  :item2 => { attr1: :word_b, attr2: :word_a },
  :item3 => {                 attr2: :word_b, attr3: :word_c }
  }
```

this produces:

```
  {:attr1=>{:word_a=>:item1,           :word_b=>:item2},
   :attr2=>{:word_b=>[:item1, :item3], :word_a=>:item2},
   :attr3=>{:word_a=>:item1,           :word_c=>:item3}}
```

**Explanation**

Consider the first element of `data_struct`, represented by `(k,v)` in the outer block:

```
k => :item1
v => { attr1: :word_a, attr2: :word_b, attr3: :word_a }
```

The inner block iterates over the elements of `v`, the first of which is:

```
k1 => :att1
v1 => :word_a
```

As `h => {}` initially,

```
h[:attr1].merge!({word_a: :item1})
  => {}.merge!({word_a: :item1})
  => {word_a: :item1}
```

`h[:attr1] => {}` because the hash was defined so that `{}` is the default value when a key is added.

The block following the `merge!` only has effect when two hashes having the same key are merged, so that does not apply in this operation.  Later, however, when we wish to `merge!`

```
{word_b: :item3}
```

with

```
h[:attr2]=>{...,word_b: :item1,...}
```

we have

```
{|:word_b,:item1,_| (:item1.is_a? Array) ? :item1<<:item3 : [:item1,:item3]}
  #=> [:item1, :item3]
```

because `:item1` is not an array.  Were there another merge for `word_b`, however, `ov` would be an array, so `op << ...` would be performed.

**Alternatives**

The expression could instead be written:

```
data_struct.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| v.each { |k1,v1|
  (h[k1] ||= {}).merge!({v1=>k}) { |key,ov,_|
    (ov.is_a? Array) ? ov << k : [ov,k] } } }
```

I agree with @theTinMan that it probably would be more useful to make all the values of the values arrays, including those containing a single element.  It also simplifies the calculation a little:

```
data_struct.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]={}}) { |(k,v),h|
  v.each { |k1,v1| h[k1].merge!({v1=>[k]}) { |key,ov,_| ov << k } } }

  #=> {:attr1=>{:word_a=>[:item1],         :word_b=>[:item2]},
  #    :attr2=>{:word_b=>[:item1, :item3], :word_a=>[:item2]},
  #    :attr3=>{:word_a=>[:item1],         :word_c=>[:item3]}}
```

Comment: This part is awesome `(h[k1] ||= {}).merge!({v1=>k})`.... +1 for overall code,, Lots things here to learn

Answer (score 1):

```
data_struct = {
  'item1' => { attr1: :word_a, attr2: :word_b, attr3: :word_a},
  'item2' => { attr1: :word_b, attr2: :word_a },
  'item3' => {                 attr2: :word_b, attr3: :word_c}
}


new_data_sturct = data_struct.inject({}) { |merged, (item, h)|
  h.each do |attr, word|
    h2 = merged[attr] ||= {}
    if h2[word]
      h2[word] = [h2[word]] unless h2[word].is_a? Array
      h2[word] << item
    else
      h2[word] = item
    end
  end
  merged
}

# => {:attr1=>{:word_a=>"item1", :word_b=>"item2"},
#     :attr2=>{:word_b=>["item1", "item3"], :word_a=>"item2"},
#     :attr3=>{:word_a=>"item1", :word_c=>"item3"}}
```

Alternative using [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), [`Hash#merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21):

```
new_data_sturct = data_struct.map {|item, h|
  Hash[h.map { |attr, word| [attr, {word => item}] }]
}.inject { |h1, h2|
  h1.merge!(h2) { |_, old, new| 
    old.merge!(new) { |_, a, b|
      (a.is_a?(Array) ? a : [a]) << b
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [`*splat`](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) operator you can make it more readable:

```
data_struct.each_with_object({}) do |(item, attrs), new_data_struct|
  attrs.each do |attr, word|
    (new_data_struct[attr] ||= {}).merge!(word => item) do |_, old_items, new_item| 
      [*old_items, new_item]
    end
  end
end
=> {:attr1=>{:word_a=>:item1, :word_b=>:item2}, 
    :attr2=>{:word_b=>[:item1, :item3], :word_a=>:item2}, 
    :attr3=>{:word_a=>:item1, :word_c=>:item3}}
```